# How do I configure configure keepalive on Centos7

Tags: centos, configuration, tcp

How and where do I configure configure TCP keepalive on CentOS 7?

My attempts to find it:

```
[michael@devserver ~]$ cat /etc/sysctl.conf
# sysctl settings are defined through files in
# /usr/lib/sysctl.d/, /run/sysctl.d/, and /etc/sysctl.d/.
#
# Vendors settings live in /usr/lib/sysctl.d/.
# To override a whole file, create a new file with the same in
# /etc/sysctl.d/ and put new settings there. To override
# only specific settings, add a file with a lexically later
# name in /etc/sysctl.d/ and put new settings there.
#
# For more information, see sysctl.conf(5) and sysctl.d(5).
[michael@devserver ~]$ cat /usr/lib/sysctl.d/* | grep keep
[michael@devserver ~]$ cat /run/sysctl.d/* | grep keep
cat: /run/sysctl.d/*: No such file or directory
[michael@devserver ~]$ cat /etc/sysctl.d/* | grep keep
[michael@devserver ~]$ cat /usr/lib/sysctl.d/* | grep keep
[michael@devserver ~]$ ls /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ | grep tcp_keep
tcp_keepalive_intvl
tcp_keepalive_probes
tcp_keepalive_time
[michael@devserver ~]$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keep*
75
9
7200
[michael@devserver ~]$ whereis tcp_keepalive
tcp_keepalive:[michael@devserver ~]$ whereis tcp_keepalived
tcp_keepalived:[michael@devserver ~]$ whereis keepalive
keepalive:[michael@devserver ~]$ whereis keepalived
keepalived:[michael@devserver ~]$ ls /etc | grep keep
[michael@greenbeantech ~]$
```

Comment: You were on the right track with your first search: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/usingkeepalive.html

Comment: @JeffSchaller  Thanks Jeff!  So, it is not a daemon which I original expected, right?  Is it now standard build into the kernel?  I seem to be able to write a new value using the "procfs"? interface.  Is there not a `conf` file?  The rest of the document described `/etc/init.d/bla` which doesn't apply to Centos 7 which uses `systemctl`, right?

Answer (score 3):

The [TCP Keepalive HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/usingkeepalive.html) refers to two methods for configuring TCP keepalives:

- the procfs interface
- the sysctl interface

As you already found, you can update the values by writing a new number to the corresponding /proc file, for example:

```
echo 600 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time
```

or via sysctl:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time=600
```

... although **neither** of those changes survive a reboot.

To make the change persist across reboots, you want to place the values in (or via) `/etc/sysctl.conf`. I don't have a CentOS system in front of me, but it's possible that /etc/sysctl.conf is linked to from a file in `/etc/sysctl.d/`.

My recommendation would be to create a file in /etc/sysctl.d/ with contents in the format:

```
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time=7200
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl=75
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes=9
```

The sysctl files are read in numeric order, so if you want your values to take precedence, heed the warning you already saw:

> To override only specific settings, add a file with a lexically later
>    name in /etc/sysctl.d/ and put new settings there.

Comment: Thanks Jeff.  As described in my initial post, I already looked in `/etc/sysctl.conf` and `/etc/sysctl.d/`, but nothing related to keepalive.  I just recently tried `sudo grep -r /etc -e tcp_keepalive_time`, and it returns no results.  I've also tried just using part of the work (i.e. "keepalive"), but still doesn't seem to be specified in `/etc/` anywhere.

Comment: Then you have the default settings; I assumed you were looking to override them.